# Matching SQL Server Modulo on a VARBINARY in C#

Tags: c#, sql, hash

Some time back we implemented a slight variation of this [Optimizing Protected Indexes](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/optimizing-protected-indexes-was-indexing-encrypted-data) approach from SQL Server Central to indexing encrypted data in the ufn_GroupData sample function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fncGetBucket]    
(  
    @String NVARCHAR(3500) 
) 
RETURNS INT   
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @Result INT = NULL;  
    IF @String IS NOT NULL
        SET @Result = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @String) % 20000;  
    RETURN @Result;   
END
```

A few million rows are happily stored in the database using the result of this UDF as a "bucketing" index.

Now we would like to be able to generate the matching bucket value in C# and the deceptively simple SQL above doesn't make it clear how to do that.

In fact, I've found it hard to get started. But I can say this code:

```
byte[] encoded = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str));
```

generates the same hash as HASHBYTES, so I'm past the first step.

So what SQL is actually doing with that modulo operator???

All help appreciated!

Comment: Looks like it just truncates the hash to the bottom four bytes and converts it to `int` then does the modulo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2fd93fdc7a7e7fe737a790f4dff1386. So probably not doing what you think it does. You should probably consider using bit-twiddling to create the buckets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HASHBYTES('SHA2_256')` returns a 32 byte ByteArray

What internally is happening is

```
cast(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @String) as int) % 20000
```

So there's an integer overflow here that is gracefully ignored by SQL Server.
**This is undefined behaviour** and not easily converted to C#.

You can achieve something similar by taking the last 4 bytes and modulo those.
This seems to work for your mod 20000.

```
byte[] encoded = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("asdf"));

var last4Bytes = encoded.Skip(28).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray();
var myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(last4Bytes);
var moduloResult = myInt % 20000;
```

This gives me the same result as

```
print HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'asdf') % 20000
```

> 12635

Comment: Via a string?? You can get the int32 directly; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-6.0#system-bitconverter-toint32(system-byte()-system-int32) Not sure if you'd have to swap the endian order afterwards though.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman good advice, I changed it. It was easier to compare to the hex values in SQL Server.

Comment: Though I'd use `if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(encoded, 28, 4); myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(encoded, 28);`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yeah, you're right. Although i think if he needs this it would belong in a library. If he just wants to create buckets for his hash values then the byte order shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks @Charles and @JeramyLakeman!! I've got some testing to do, but I confirm success!

One little thing about my scenario for the record - the use of NVARCHAR in the UDF requires Encoding.Unicode on the C# side.